# Cannot build Docker windows image on Azure Devops hosted agent

Tags: docker, azure-pipelines, windows-container

I am trying to write a build pipeline in Azure DevOps that will compile an application and build a windows docker image. The building of the application is fine and I have a Dockerfile checked in but when the build image task is run I get the following error.

```
"The container operating system does not match the host operating system."
```

The build agents I have tried are "windows-latest" and "windows-2022" which are more than likely the same thing.

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2022'

- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build an image
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: 'MyContainerRegistry'
    repository: '$(project.name)'
    command: 'build'
    Dockerfile: '$(project.folder)/Dockerfile'
```

I would understand this error if I was attempting to do this on a Linux host but because I am using a windows host I'm not sure what the issue is.

The base image in the DockerFile is:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:20H2
```

Comment: Hi psycho, we did some more test, and we found that we pull docker file FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:20H2 successfully with docker build task, cli task of docker build and even local command line. So we are wondering in which layer of building the image you got this mismatch error message. Have you rechecked the commands in your dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message describing, I suppose that you need to validate the container image version with the host version again before your retest. You could try to change a docker container version or switch to `windows-2019 image`.

When referencing the doc for [Windows container version compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility?tabs=windows-server-2022%2Cwindows-11#windows-server-containers:%7E:text=For%20any%20other%20scenario%20where%20there%20is%20a%20mismatch%20in%20host/guest%20Windows%20versioning%20compatibility%20between%20User/Kernel%20mode%20is%20possible%2C%20but%20not%20guaranteed%2C%20and%20thus%20the%20container%20image%20will%20be%20prevented%20from%20running%20on%20the%20host.), I found the readness below. And you could look into more compatibility.

> For any other scenario where there is a mismatch in host/guest Windows
> versioning compatibility between User/Kernel mode is possible, but not
> guaranteed, and thus the container image will be prevented from
> running on the host.

By the way, below is list for docker image version compatible with [Window server 2022](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-server)

[image]

Last but not lease, it is also important to follow the [Base Image Lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/base-image-lifecycle) in developing.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I tried running the pipeline with 2019 host and I also used 2022 with the 10.0.20348.1249 image and it also failed

Comment: @psycho hi, is it working if you run via self hosted agent?

Comment: That will be my last option. I will need to figure out how get windows docker set up on a windows server

Comment: I'm not sure Azure DevOps supports Windows Server 2022 yet, so the comment above to change the tag would only work if the image is also on Windows Server 2019. That means you need to change the dockerfile as well.